# Processing of text

Tags: replace

It is pleasure to ask you about something I cannot solve myself. I am working with big text files with many similar lines. The format of the files is defined and I want to replace repetitively some characters appearing in some columns of the files. For example I would like to substitute in a file similar to this below, when the last number 3.0e-4 is, from the 5th to the 7th character by aaa, in this case yyy will be substitute by aaa:

```
ASDEFxxx          3.0E+12ERT          SAA      1.0e-4
ASEEFyyy          4.0E+12EDT          ABA      3.0e-4
ASAEFzzz          5.0E+12ERF          ADA      2.0e-4
```

In this example I would like to use replace regexp to replace in this case only the second line. The result should be:

```
ASDEFxxx          3.0E+12ERT          SAA      1.0e-4
ASEEFaaa          4.0E+12EDT          ABA      3.0e-4
ASAEFzzz          5.0E+12ERF          ADA      2.0e-4
```

There are many lines in the file to be substituted...

Does anybody write the command with replace regexp to do that?

Thanks and regards,
Manuel

Comment: You could write a macro.

Comment: (@Ista means *keyboard* macro, presumably.)

Comment: Yes, I meant record a keyboard macro. Thanks @Drew

Comment: Our of curiosity, how many lines is "big"? A keyboard macro won't really scale on the order of 100,000, and another method I'm thinking of won't scale beyond 1,000. (`replace-regexp` is the fastest method I know from a performance perspective)

Comment: Yes the file is about 500000 lines. I was exactly looking for this replace-regexp command. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `\(.\{5\}\).\{3\}\(.*3.0e-4\)` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\1aaa\2` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Dissection:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> select the whole file
- <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> run `query-replace-regexp` (you may want <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` instead)
- `\(.\{5\}\)` capture 5 characters into the group `\1`.
- `.\{3\}` match three characters (will discard)
- `\(.*3.0e-4\)` match the rest of the line, ensuring `3.0e-4` and capture in `\2`

Comment: Hi PythonNut,
Many thanks for your answer. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks and regards
Manuel